# Tool for re-permissioning Citrix published apps?

Tags: permissions, command-line-interface, citrix

We have Citrix XenApp 4.0/4.5/5.0 farms with hundreds of published applications which we will need to edit, preferably through a scriptable command-line tool. I've searched the Citrix Administrator's Guides and their [troubleshooting tool list](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX107572), but I'm returning empty-handed.

Can someone recommend any tools that can view and edit Citrix published app permissions, besides the normal GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would have been great. I never stumbled upon a really useful tool which could do that.
Thomas Koetzing has a almost complete [Resource Kit](http://www.thomaskoetzing.de/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=119&Itemid=193&lang=en) which contains many tools any (citrix) admin may find helpful.

But I always ended up scripting using the [Citrix SDK](http://community.citrix.com/p/sdkcentral#xenapp)

A really [good guide covering the Citrix SDK](http://community.citrix.com/download/attachments/29851654/UltimateGuideToMFCOM.pdf?version=1)

Comment: I'm checking out the SDKs now... The abandoned PowerShell Commands CTP looks like it would be great; but the MFCOM will probably work for all versions we have. Thanks, Tom!

Comment: For Xenapp 6 and 6.5 the official Citrix-Powershell-Snapin is great. Don't know if there is a snapin for 5. For 4.5 or lower there is no official snapin available. You're welcome